# jQuery: request full screen not working on iPhone, iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, fullscreen

jQuery request full screen not working on iPhone, iPad both Chrome and Safari Browser.
Here is the code that I used

```
if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
}
else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
}
else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
else if (element.webkitEnterFullscreen) {
    element.webkitEnterFullscreen();
}
else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Safari it wont work because it's not supported according to https://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen

And as far as I know Chrome for iOS is based on Safari, which means that fullscreen api is also not supported.
Sadly iOS and HTML- fullscreen experiences is a huge deal.